# A weak character vs weak character

Tags: articles

I am reading a translation book and it says that it is wrong to say "He is of weak character." because there is an adjective before "character", so an indefinite article is needed: "He is of a weak character."

But I have found sentences like "It is a sign of weak character" without an indefinite article before "character". Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: May I ask what book  on translation you are reading? Please note though: x of y is not: of y. In any case, one would write: He ***has*** a weak character. Both examples are probably poor translations because **of a weak character** or **of weak character** are old-fashioned. So unless there is justification for it they both "sound" like what is called translationese. Or they sound like 19th century literary forms. Dickens, for instance. [I will make this an answer, if you can tell me the title of the book.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use 'of' to link a person or thing to a noun denoting a quality preceded by an adjective is perfectly grammatical and, although formal, by no means old fashioned.

> "As Friedrich Nietzsche remarks, to be a person of character is to have one’s characteristic experience (1886, p.80). The life of **a person of weak character** will lack much of a unifying thread of this sort" - Character by Joel J. Kupperman (1995)
>
> "For, in reality, a man **of weak character** lurks behind the solid image: a man who is both a philanderer and a spendthrift permanently in debt." 
>   Authority, State and National Character: The Civilizing Process in Austria 
>   By Helmut Kuzmics, Roland Axtmann (2017)
>
> "It was his hope also that the limiting conditions attached to the offer of sovereignty would enable him to exercise a strong personal control over a man **of weak character** like Anjou."
>   History of Holland by George Edmundson (2013)
>
> "Daniel was a man **of strong character**, and had a deep love to please God in every way." 
>   Sermon Central (2008)
>
> "The real colonizer is almost of necessity a man **of strong character**, a creator rather than an accepter of relationships."
>   Prospero and Caliban: The Psychology of Colonization by Octave Mannoni (1990)
>
> "Topical chloramphenicol prophylaxis is **of dubious benefit** in corneal abrasion."
>   Emerg Med Australas. (2010)
>
> "If pharmaceutical companies use a major part of the enhanced net revenues they gain from patent protection to finance large marketing and promotion efforts, this would be another element **of dubious benefit** to consumers."
>   The Oxford Handbook of Business Ethics by George G. Brenkert, ‎Tom L. Beauchamp (2012)

Comment: I would have agreed that *"**of** weak character"* sounds old-fashioned, but your examples show that it's perfectly contemporary.  +1

Comment: This sort of construction, with or without modifiers, is extremely common: noun - of- [adjective] noun of character - a thing of beauty, a note of warning, a plan of merit, an argument of weight, a person of charisma, a period of hope, a time of waiting - I could carry on forever.

Comment: Yes, all those ones you give in your comment, I agree with. I don't agree with some of the others are seen all the time.  And I note that the Austrian one might refer to a translation and the one on Nietzsche is invokes German  indirectly and is also old-fashioned in that sense. The same goes for the history of Anjou and the Bible one. A man of a weak character or of weak character harkens backwards, no matter how one writes it.

Comment: "the Austrian one might be a translation." Did you mean the quote from  Emergency Medicine Australasia? Australasia comprises (mainly) Australia (where kangaroos come from) and New Zealand (where kiwis live). They are both English-speaking countries in the British Commonwealth. Austria is a small landlocked country in central Europe where wiener schnitzels come from, where they speak German.

Comment: "invokes German indirectly and is also old-fashioned in that sense." That doesn't make any sense.